# WebDriverException on RobotFramework simple login script

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, browser-automation

I just started learning RobotFramework with Selenium2Library and I can't get to fix an issue on a simple script.

**Environment:**

- Linux Mint
- Selenium2Library
- Firefox 35.0.1
- Python 2.7.6

**RobotFramework Test Case**

```
*** Settings ***
Library            Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Verify that user can see his or her name on logging onto Facebook
      Navigate to Facebook
      Input text                id=mad        johndoe@gmail.com
      Input password            id=pass          mypassword
      Click Button              id=u_0_l
      Page should contain       John Doe

*** Keywords ***
Navigate to Facebook
      Open Browser    firefox
      Go to           http://www.facebook.com
```

**Exception**

```
Full Name:  Loginfb.Verify that user can see his or her name on logging onto Facebook
Start / End / Elapsed:  20150219 15:29:02.749 / 20150219 15:29:06.655 / 00:00:03.906
Status:     FAIL (critical)
Message:    WebDriverException: Message: f.QueryInterface is not a function Stacktrace: at FirefoxDriver.prototype.get (file:///tmp/tmp6FDy0N/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9504:13) at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmp6FDy0N/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:16) at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp6FDy0N/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11640:7) at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmp6FDy0N/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11582:5)
```

Answer (score -1):

found the problem : 
      Open Browser    https://www.facebook.com  Firefox 
      Go to           https://www.facebook.com